# How to make React to ignore some folder files updates and don't recompile?

Tags: reactjs

I've got problem - on some requests backend creates static html files in frontend subfolder which causes React to recompile and reload page. This is bad for me.

If simplify, I've got following project directory structure:

```
backend/
  ...
frontend/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  public/
    statements/
    ...
  src/
  webpack.config.js
  ...
...
```

I want React to ignore `public/statements` folder updates.

How could I make it?

Found that maybe I should configure Webpack exlude rule, but I failed to do it.

UPD1: Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /public/
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

UPD2: Tried also this one, same trouble:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'statements'),
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in the webpack.config.js file set the rules property array and set exclude folder
like this

```
 module: {
  rules: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /public/statements/
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried to do it and failed again. Included my `webpack.config.js` to question, please look at it, am I doing it right?

Comment: add the test property as well and try

Comment: Another question - where should I place Webpack config?

Comment: in the root folder

Comment: Added `test` property, same trouble, page reloads. BTW what `test` means?

Comment: test checks for the extensions of the files that you want to ignore

Answer (score 1):

For HMR reloading?

```
devServer: {
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'statements'),
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide full Webpack config example?

Comment: I've added to question my config created basing on your answer. Unfortunately could not make it work.